# Codeigniter - Call to undefined function set_value()

Tags: codeigniter, setvalue

im new on codeigniter and try to resolve following problem for hours now.
I try to set_value in a form but when i set it i get following error:

*A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to undefined function set_value()
Filename: modals/register_modal.php
Line Number: 27
Backtrace:*

When i delete set_value() on line 27, everything works fine.

Line number 27 is the set_value() line:

```
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label sr-only">Vorname:</label>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Vorname" value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>" size="50" />
   <i class="fa form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thats my controller:

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->helper('form');

                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Vorname', 'required|callback_username_check');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('surename', 'Nachname', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Passwort', 'required');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        $this->load->view('modals/register_modal');
                }
                else
                {
                        $this->load->view('modals/login_modal');
                }
        }

        public function username_check($str)
        {
                if ($str == 'test')
                {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
                        return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }

}
```

I also set Auto-Load:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

Comment: You don't have to load form helper twice. Leave it in autoload only to have it globally in all controllers, but remove from controller. Also, change the name of controller to avoid possible name collision since CodeIgniter already has Form class. After all, autoload url helper too.

Comment: Thank you, changed everything but still the same problem. Is there any order to set in autoload?

Comment: Not much because all classes loaded in `autoload.php` are loaded before controllers. Basic sample from documentation works or not for you?

Comment: Yes the basic sample works fine. I thought i can take it 1:1 with my own form and controller but i went wrong.

Comment: Maybe i get this error because my form is in a modal...

Comment: Try to narrow your code to conclude when exactly you get the error. 
Is modal fully loaded at once or is it loaded through AJAX afterward? 
Post your files on pastebin.com and link it to let us see whole story instead of code snippets.

Comment: I had look in here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value  and says todo `<?php echo set_value('firstname', 'something'); ?>`

Answer (score 10):

You must load `library('form_validation')` in your Controller.
This work for me:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
    }
....
```

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter4 you have only to use the *helper* function to load the library

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\UserModel;
class Users extends BaseController {
public function index()
{
    helper (['form']);   
    ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Add helper HTML

```
protected $helpers = ['form','url','html'];
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
helper(['form']);
```

Load the form helper in your function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add form helper in BaseController.php. you don't need to add in every cotnroller - codeigniter 4

Edit in BaseController.php

```
protected $helpers = ['form'];
```